# Aptana can't update or add pluggin

Tags: aptana, aptana3

Hello and thanks by advance for the help.
I'm having an issue on Aptana. If I try to update or to add a new pluggin, an error popup appear with the following message :

An internal error occurred during: "Contacting Software Sites".
org/eclipse/ecf/core/identity/ID.

My config :
Ubuntu 12.10 with cinnamon
Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.3.1.201212171919

```
the last Error log
******************
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2013-01-23 13:06:06.236
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Contacting Software Sites".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/ecf/core/identity/ID
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.defineClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClassHoldingLock(ClasspathManager.java:626)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:562)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:486)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.RepositoryTransport.download(RepositoryTransport.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.RepositoryTransport.download(RepositoryTransport.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadIndexFile(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:721)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:640)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.LoadMetadataRepositoryJob.doLoad(LoadMetadataRepositoryJob.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.LoadMetadataRepositoryJob.runModal(LoadMetadataRepositoryJob.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.sdk.PreloadingRepositoryHandler$2.runModal(PreloadingRepositoryHandler.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations.ProvisioningJob.run(ProvisioningJob.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter$TerminatingClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.ecf.identity (440).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.defineClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClassHoldingLock(ClasspathManager.java:626)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:562)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:486)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.RepositoryTransport.download(RepositoryTransport.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.RepositoryTransport.download(RepositoryTransport.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadIndexFile(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:721)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:640)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.updatechecker.UpdateChecker.getAvailableRepositories(UpdateChecker.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.updatechecker.UpdateChecker.checkForUpdates(UpdateChecker.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.updatechecker.UpdateChecker$UpdateCheckThread.run(UpdateChecker.java:72)
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.ecf.internal.core.identity.Activator.start() of bundle org.eclipse.ecf.identity.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/eclipse/ecf/core/identity/BaseID, method: implies signature: (Ljavax/security/auth/Subject;)Z) Illegal use of nonvirtual function call
    at org.eclipse.ecf.core.identity.StringID$StringIDNamespace.<init>(StringID.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.core.identity.IDFactory.<clinit>(IDFactory.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.internal.core.identity.Activator.start(Activator.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    ... 40 more


A part of the aptana config
***************************
*** System properties:
awt.toolkit=sun.awt.X11.XToolkit
eclipse.application=com.aptana.rcp.application
eclipse.buildId=3.3.1.201212171919
eclipse.commands=-os
linux
-ws
gtk
-arch
x86_64
-showsplash
-launcher
/opt/Aptana_Studio_3/AptanaStudio3
-name
AptanaStudio3
--launcher.library
/opt/Aptana_Studio_3//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.100.v20110505/eclipse_1407.so
-startup
/opt/Aptana_Studio_3//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-exitdata
160004
-vm
/usr/bin/java
eclipse.home.location=file:/opt/Aptana_Studio_3/
eclipse.launcher=/opt/Aptana_Studio_3/AptanaStudio3
eclipse.launcher.name=AptanaStudio3
eclipse.log.backup.max=5
eclipse.log.size.max=10000
eclipse.p2.data.area=@config.dir/../p2/
eclipse.p2.profile=AptanaProfile
eclipse.p2.unsignedPolicy=allow
eclipse.product=com.aptana.rcp.product
eclipse.startTime=1358940458057
eclipse.vm=/usr/bin/java
eclipse.vmargs=-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-Declipse.p2.unsignedPolicy=allow
-Declipse.log.size.max=10000
-Declipse.log.backup.max=5
-Djava.awt.headless=true
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jar
/opt/Aptana_Studio_3//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
equinox.use.ds=true
file.encoding=UTF-8
file.encoding.pkg=sun.io
file.separator=/
java.awt.graphicsenv=sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment
java.awt.headless=true
java.awt.printerjob=sun.print.PSPrinterJob
java.class.path=/opt/Aptana_Studio_3//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
java.class.version=52.0
java.endorsed.dirs=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/endorsed
java.ext.dirs=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext:/usr/java/packages/lib/ext
java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
java.library.path=/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
java.runtime.name=Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
java.runtime.version=1.8.0-ea-b73
java.specification.name=Java Platform API Specification
java.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation
java.specification.version=1.8
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
java.vendor.url=http://java.oracle.com/
java.vendor.url.bug=http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/
java.version=1.8.0-ea
java.vm.info=mixed mode
java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
java.vm.specification.name=Java Virtual Machine Specification
java.vm.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation
java.vm.specification.version=1.8
java.vm.vendor=Oracle Corporation
java.vm.version=25.0-b14
line.separator=

org.eclipse.debug.ui.breakpoints.toggleFactoriesUsed=false
org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.splash.location=/opt/Aptana_Studio_3/configuration/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher/com.aptana.rcp_3.3.1.201212171919/splash.bmp
org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator.configUrl=file:org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator/bundles.info
org.eclipse.update.reconcile=false
org.osgi.framework.executionenvironment=OSGi/Minimum-1.0,OSGi/Minimum-1.1,OSGi/Minimum-1.2,JRE-1.1,J2SE-1.2,J2SE-1.3,J2SE-1.4,J2SE-1.5,JavaSE-1.6,JavaSE-1.7
org.osgi.framework.language=fr
org.osgi.framework.os.name=Linux
org.osgi.framework.os.version=3.5.0
org.osgi.framework.processor=x86-64
org.osgi.framework.system.capabilities=osgi.ee; osgi.ee="OSGi/Minimum"; version:List<Version>="1.0, 1.1, 1.2",osgi.ee; osgi.ee="JavaSE"; version:List<Version>="1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7"
org.osgi.framework.system.packages=javax.accessibility,javax.activation,javax.activity,javax.annotation,javax.annotation.processing,javax.crypto,javax.crypto.interfaces,javax.crypto.spec,javax.imageio,javax.imageio.event,javax.imageio.metadata,javax.imageio.plugins.bmp,javax.imageio.plugins.jpeg,javax.imageio.spi,javax.imageio.stream,javax.jws,javax.jws.soap,javax.lang.model,javax.lang.model.element,javax.lang.model.type,javax.lang.model.util,javax.management,javax.management.event,javax.management.loading,javax.management.modelmbean,javax.management.monitor,javax.management.namespace,javax.management.openmbean,javax.management.relation,javax.management.remote,javax.management.remote.rmi,javax.management.timer,javax.naming,javax.naming.directory,javax.naming.event,javax.naming.ldap,javax.naming.spi,javax.net,javax.net.ssl,javax.print,javax.print.attribute,javax.print.attribute.standard,javax.print.event,javax.rmi,javax.rmi.CORBA,javax.rmi.ssl,javax.script,javax.security.auth,javax.security.auth.callback,javax.security.auth.kerberos,javax.security.auth.login,javax.security.auth.spi,javax.security.auth.x500,javax.security.cert,javax.security.sasl,javax.sound.midi,javax.sound.midi.spi,javax.sound.sampled,javax.sound.sampled.spi,javax.sql,javax.sql.rowset,javax.sql.rowset.serial,javax.sql.rowset.spi,javax.swing,javax.swing.border,javax.swing.colorchooser,javax.swing.event,javax.swing.filechooser,javax.swing.plaf,javax.swing.plaf.basic,javax.swing.plaf.metal,javax.swing.plaf.multi,javax.swing.plaf.nimbus,javax.swing.plaf.synth,javax.swing.table,javax.swing.text,javax.swing.text.html,javax.swing.text.html.parser,javax.swing.text.rtf,javax.swing.tree,javax.swing.undo,javax.tools,javax.transaction,javax.transaction.xa,javax.xml,javax.xml.bind,javax.xml.bind.annotation,javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters,javax.xml.bind.attachment,javax.xml.bind.helpers,javax.xml.bind.util,javax.xml.crypto,javax.xml.crypto.dom,javax.xml.crypto.dsig,javax.xml.crypto.dsig.dom,javax.xml.crypto.dsig.keyinfo,javax.xml.crypto.dsig.spec,javax.xml.datatype,javax.xml.namespace,javax.xml.parsers,javax.xml.soap,javax.xml.stream,javax.xml.stream.events,javax.xml.stream.util,javax.xml.transform,javax.xml.transform.dom,javax.xml.transform.sax,javax.xml.transform.stax,javax.xml.transform.stream,javax.xml.validation,javax.xml.ws,javax.xml.ws.handler,javax.xml.ws.handler.soap,javax.xml.ws.http,javax.xml.ws.soap,javax.xml.ws.spi,javax.xml.ws.spi.http,javax.xml.ws.wsaddressing,javax.xml.xpath,org.ietf.jgss,org.omg.CORBA,org.omg.CORBA_2_3,org.omg.CORBA_2_3.portable,org.omg.CORBA.DynAnyPackage,org.omg.CORBA.ORBPackage,org.omg.CORBA.portable,org.omg.CORBA.TypeCodePackage,org.omg.CosNaming,org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextExtPackage,org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage,org.omg.Dynamic,org.omg.DynamicAny,org.omg.DynamicAny.DynAnyFactoryPackage,org.omg.DynamicAny.DynAnyPackage,org.omg.IOP,org.omg.IOP.CodecFactoryPackage,org.omg.IOP.CodecPackage,org.omg.Messaging,org.omg.PortableInterceptor,org.omg.PortableInterceptor.ORBInitInfoPackage,org.omg.PortableServer,org.omg.PortableServer.CurrentPackage,org.omg.PortableServer.POAManagerPackage,org.omg.PortableServer.POAPackage,org.omg.PortableServer.portable,org.omg.PortableServer.ServantLocatorPackage,org.omg.SendingContext,org.omg.stub.java.rmi,org.w3c.dom,org.w3c.dom.bootstrap,org.w3c.dom.css,org.w3c.dom.events,org.w3c.dom.html,org.w3c.dom.ls,org.w3c.dom.ranges,org.w3c.dom.stylesheets,org.w3c.dom.traversal,org.w3c.dom.views,org.w3c.dom.xpath,org.xml.sax,org.xml.sax.ext,org.xml.sax.helpers
org.osgi.framework.uuid=50cc6fe4-4f65-0012-1c56-fd2bf80d8562
org.osgi.framework.vendor=Eclipse
org.osgi.framework.version=1.6.0
org.osgi.supports.framework.extension=true
org.osgi.supports.framework.fragment=true
org.osgi.supports.framework.requirebundle=true
os.arch=amd64
os.name=Linux
os.version=3.5.0-22-generic
osgi.arch=x86_64
osgi.bundles=reference:file:org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.200.v20110815-1438.jar@1:start
osgi.bundles.defaultStartLevel=4
osgi.bundlestore=/opt/Aptana_Studio_3/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles
osgi.configuration.area=file:/opt/Aptana_Studio_3/configuration/
osgi.framework=file:/opt/Aptana_Studio_3/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.7.2.v20120110-1415.jar
osgi.framework.extensions=
osgi.framework.shape=jar
osgi.framework.version=3.7.2.v20120110-1415
osgi.install.area=file:/opt/Aptana_Studio_3/
osgi.instance.area=file:/home/tony/Lociciels/ubuntu/install/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/
osgi.instance.area.default=file:/home/tony/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/
osgi.logfile=/home/tony/Lociciels/ubuntu/install/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/.metadata/.log
osgi.manifest.cache=/opt/Aptana_Studio_3/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/manifests
osgi.nl=fr_FR
osgi.os=linux
osgi.splashLocation=/opt/Aptana_Studio_3/configuration/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher/com.aptana.rcp_3.3.1.201212171919/splash.bmp
osgi.splashPath=platform:/base/plugins/com.aptana.rcp
osgi.syspath=/opt/Aptana_Studio_3/plugins
osgi.tracefile=/home/tony/Lociciels/ubuntu/install/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/.metadata/trace.log
osgi.ws=gtk
path.separator=:
sun.arch.data.model=64
sun.boot.class.path=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/classes
sun.boot.library.path=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64
sun.cpu.endian=little
sun.cpu.isalist=
sun.desktop=gnome
sun.io.unicode.encoding=UnicodeLittle
sun.java.command=/opt/Aptana_Studio_3//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -showsplash -launcher /opt/Aptana_Studio_3/AptanaStudio3 -name AptanaStudio3 --launcher.library /opt/Aptana_Studio_3//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.100.v20110505/eclipse_1407.so -startup /opt/Aptana_Studio_3//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar --launcher.overrideVmargs -exitdata 160004 -vm /usr/bin/java -vmargs -Xms40m -Xmx512m -Declipse.p2.unsignedPolicy=allow -Declipse.log.size.max=10000 -Declipse.log.backup.max=5 -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -jar /opt/Aptana_Studio_3//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
sun.java.launcher=SUN_STANDARD
sun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8
sun.management.compiler=HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
sun.os.patch.level=unknown
user.country=FR
user.dir=/home/tony
user.home=/home/tony
user.language=fr
user.name=tony
user.timezone=Europe/Paris

*** Features:
com.aptana.feature (3.3.1.1355795126-BP7P8JBebBpDEmXx71DC44EXt-dS) "Aptana Studio 3"
com.aptana.feature.rcp (3.3.1.201212171919-7o7lFDDFFeFt-ajpeO4csz0uKWjZ) "Aptana Studio 3"
com.aptana.feature.studio (3.3.1.201212171835-7G7F07UIRYTaR0Q6Sz-8biKsz0da) "Aptana Studio 3"
com.aptana.php.feature (3.3.0.201212171814-7J7E-7IOVQZXgWOT) "Aptana PHP Editor"
com.aptana.pydev.feature (2.7.0.2012110722-7g9I-8Jez0Iz-z-gwJI) "Pydev - Python Development Environment"
org.eclipse.help (1.3.0.v20110530-0844-7i7uFFmFFl8nvqbDpEqTvx) "Help System Base"
org.eclipse.platform (3.7.2.v20120207-1839-9gF7UHPDFxGjd-PqDr2jX_4yKaumkoHTz04_q-q) "Eclipse Platform"
org.eclipse.rcp (3.7.2.v20120120-1424-9DB5FmnFq5JCf1UA38R-kz0S0272) "Eclipse RCP"
org.radrails.rails (3.3.0.201212171824-7e-7Q7f5FNTNHIZ_) "Aptana Ruby Editor"
```

Comment: do you have the same problem with fresh aptana install on the clean/new workspace? If so, for which plugin installation do you get the error?

Comment: Must be Java related, I get the same error with Eclipse and ZendStudio. I run Java 1.8 as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yup, it's Java 1.8 related.

I just installed Java 1.7 along side 1.8 and starting Eclipse and ZendStudio using Java 1.7 makes the update work again.

Comment: Yes it is a bug in Java8 - See https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=399801

Comment: @AnthonyLellouche if that solutino works for you please upvote and mark this answer as closed.